# How to generate an random 8 character string that won't occur twice in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

How do I generate a random string that is only 8 characters long, that will not occur twice in jQuery.

Comment: This will be difficult unless you can check the history of the numbers you have generated somehow.

Comment: The specifications random and not occur twice are incompatible - if it is truly random then obviously the probability of any sequence occurring is not dependant on the history of past occurances. What you want I suspect is a pseudorandom sequence generator with a maximal length sequence - you could then store the state of such a generator rather than store all past sequences. The web site http://www.cfn.upenn.edu/aguirre/wiki/public:m_sequences has details on how to generate a maximal length pseudorandom sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just use the current time (as an integer)?

Comment: Depending upon the lifetime you have to operate over, 8 digits may not be enough and if you need a whole bunch of random numbers quickly, the current time may not advance fast enough.  Time is generally a good thing to use for a non-repeating unique number, but the 8 digit limitation might handicap that for this particular use.

Comment: This will not be 8 characters long.

Comment: Great idea just pared it with jQuery, as the date with the integers in the date that won't be the same over time. Very Good Idea!

Answer (score 0):

This will generate the desired range of random numbers and keep a history of previously generated numbers so it will never generate the same number twice:

```
function generateRandom() {
    if (!generateRandom.prevNums) {
        generateRandom.prevNums = {};
    }
    var random;
    do {
        random = Math.floor((Math.random() * (99999999 - 10000000 + 1)) + 10000000);
    } while (generateRandom.prevNums[random])
    generateRandom.prevNums[random] = true;
    return(random.toString());
}
```

Working demonstration here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/ZfKmk/

Comment: this will work nicely if the OP is interested in a given session. You'd need to store these in a cookie across multiple sessions, and even that won't work if he's interested in a unique number across multiple browsers (to say nothing of users).

Comment: @Dr.Dredel - If you need unique across multiple browsers, then you have to have a central server involved.  No client solution can do that.  If you need it across multiple sessions within one browser, then you have to have a place to store the previously generated numbers (like HTML5 storage).  Neither of those requirements were specified in the OP's question (which was vague about a lot of details).

Comment: agreed... I was simply covering his (vaguely unstated) bases. As I said, your answer is definitely a terrific one, if his requirements are as you anticipate. I just thought I'd clarify... one never knows what may be obvious to you, may be totally opaque to the questioner.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is exactly what you're asking for.  At any time in your code, you can ask for a random, 8-character string via `rString.get()`:

```
   var rString = {
       get : function() {
           var _this = this,
               randomString,
               charset = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789!@#$%^&*()-=_+".split('');

           var generate = function(len) {
               var output = '';
               for(var i=0; i<len; i++) {
                   output += charset[ Math.floor(Math.random()*charset.length) ];
               }
               return output;
           }

           var inArray = function(arr, item) {
               for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
                   if(arr[i] === item) {
                       return true;
                   }
               }
               return false;
           }

           while( true ) {
               if( !inArray( this.previous, randomString = generate(8) ) ) {
                   this.previous.push(randomString);
                   return randomString;
               }
           }

       },
       previous : []
   };
```

[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thejase/ZTmDF/1/) will generate 10 random items for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean won't occur twice anywhere (meaning, on other people's computers, or in different browsers on the client's computer) then the short answer is, in pure javascript that's simply not possible, since that relies on getting a user's network SSID to use as a key, and javascript doesn't have access to that.

If you mean a random number that won't repeat on the user's client over some period of days (or until they clear their cookies), then grab a random number, take 8 digits from it and put it in a cookie. Then test against that cookie when you get the next number (and store that as well).  That guarantees a unique number for that user, in that browser.

If you mean won't repeat simply in a given session, then jfriend's answer is your best bet.